# How to create a calendar of single week as scooll calendar

Tags: android, calendar

[image]I would create in my application a weekly calendar, one week, like the school to understand. I would then add the events in the week. To do this I searched the old questions and libraries but could not find what I was looking for. Have you any idea how I can do this?

what I want to create should look like this

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this](https://github.com/Mulham-Raee/Horizontal-Calendar?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=5087) library for horizontal week view, and on click on each date you can show that days tasks.

Comment: I'm not sure that this library allows me to do what I need. I updated my question with an example

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I had already seen this library, but I have not been able to block the view of a single week. I only need the one-week days. you can do this with the library?